# What field in Django Rest Framework allow POST data combining FileField and IntegerField?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to write a viewset in Django Rest Framework which allow user upload a list of new **Images with these Order number together**. But I don't know what field to use in DRF.

My serializer:

```
class ContentSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    fileUpload = FileField(max_length=100000, allow_empty_file=False, use_url=False)
    order_num = IntegerField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = [
            'fileUpload',
            'order_num',
        ]

class ArticleSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    file_uploads = ListField(child=ContentSerializer(),write_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = [
            'file_uploads',
        ]
```

My Viewset:

```
class FeedEditAPIView(ModelViewSet):
    '''
    Use Form Data to PATCH
    '''
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    lookup_field = 'id'


    def edit_article(self, request, id):
        print request.POST.getlist('file_uploads') // This return [u'{"file":{},"order_num":0}']
```

When I print request POST file_uploads, it return `[u'{"file":{},"order_num":0}']`. But I want to return `[u'{"file":<files_object>,"order_num":0}']` instead of

Comment: did you try `print(request.FILES)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `multipartparser`, which supports file uploads and request.data

```
class FeedEditAPIView(ModelViewSet):
    '''
    Use Form Data to PATCH
    '''
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)

    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    lookup_field = 'id'
```

Comment: Thank you Raja Simon very much!

Comment: How can I request data from Client? Please check [my question][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51721680/append-object-which-contain-file-and-string-value-into-formdata-js