# Append object which contain File and String value into FormData - JS

Tags: javascript, multipartform-data, form-data

I'm finding a solution to append object which contain File and String value into FormData and send it to server (MultiPartParser of Django Rest FrameWork).

Console.log(file)
[image]

Now my code is:

```
Fd.append('file_uploads', JSON.stringify({ 'file': file, 'order_num': 1 }) )
```

When I console.log this value of form data, it returns `{"file":{},"order_num":1}`. You can see **file value is empty**.

I tried to remove `JSON.stringify`:

```
Fd.append('file_uploads', { 'file': file, 'order_num': 1 } )
```

When I console.log this value of form data, it returns `[object, object]`.

I want the results is

`{"file":<file_object>,"order_num":1}`

Comment: What you get in `console.log(files)`

Comment: @RajaSimon edited with photo Above, bro

Comment: Can you try this `Fd.append('file_uploads', file, 'your_filename_here');`

Comment: @RajaSimon It's ok. But I want to send to server JSON string `{"file":<file_object>,"order_num":1}`

Comment: Okay why not append another one like this `Fd.append('json_load', {..})` in another line

Comment: Can you get more specific. I cant get what you're saying, bro

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177558/discussion-between-raja-simon-and-feed-git).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not append file object and key value with FormData. Try alternative solution like this

i.e) I will add order_no with file name and in python you can use string `split` function to  get the order_no

```
Fd.append('file_uploads', file, 'your_filename_here_and_order_no');
```